# UITableView: Drag'n'drop making space between cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop

How would I make the cells, below the one that I drag, go down, making a space for insertion?
[Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSdVop564mY&feature=channel&list=UL#t=1m50s).

I expect it to behave like following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController) is a pretty good implementation. Basically you have a a gesture recognizer to do a tap and hold and then pan around (the trick begin that you dont move the cell on the pan, you move a UIImageView with a snapshot of the cell)

As the cell moves, you detect which row is beneath, and move the table view's cells accordingly (e.g. with `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`)

Comment: Thanks! So the difference between [standard approach](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW4) and this one is ability to drag cell from any place (not by grabbing icon with 3 gray lines on the cell)?

Comment: yes. the implementation may not be the same under the hood but to the user thats the main difference